# SSH "Connection closed by XXX [preauth]" during ssh/sftp setup of network scanner

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, openssh, sshd

On my local LAN, I'm trying to setup a sftp share for network scanning, which is working as intended when connecting with `ssh`/`sftp` from my laptop.

Strangely, upon trying to set up the connection for my network scanner, I get an error message "Authentication Error" in the scanner's web-administration tool. Upon inspection, I found **Connection closed by 192.168.178.44 port 52786 [preauth]** on the ssh-server log.

Since the log is full of messages about the key exchange, I'm assuming that the client is maybe using an unusual key type, but my knowledge is limited on this. Is there a way to enable the connection anyways on the server side by editing the sshd_config? What are implications security-wise? Especially in comparison to plain FTP.

My SSH server configuration is nearly default. I'm running openssh on port 2022 on a RaspberryPi (192.168.178.100).

Attached log from `journalctl -xe` when trying to connect from network scanner (192.168.178.44, Brother ADS-4300N):

```
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: Connection from 192.168.178.44 port 52786 on 192.168.178.100 port 2022 rdomain ""
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Raspbian-5+deb11u1
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh2_1.9.0
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: no match: libssh2_1.9.0
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing seccomp filter sandbox
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: Network child is on pid 6320
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: preauth child monitor started
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: privsep user:group 107:65534 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 107/65534 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: setting PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: attaching seccomp filter program [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]                                                                                                                                   
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256 [preauth]                                                                                                       
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]                                                                                                                                  
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]                                                                                              
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]                                                                                              
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]                                                                                                                             
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]                                                                                                                             
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]                                                                                                       
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc [preauth]                                                        
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc [preauth]                                                        
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com [preauth]                                                                                            
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com [preauth]                                                                                            
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: compression ctos: none [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: compression stoc: none [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: mm_sshkey_sign entering [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: mm_answer_sign
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: mm_answer_sign: KEX signature 0x152b3b8(399)
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
Aug 29 20:41:42 Nas sshd[6319]: Connection closed by 192.168.178.44 port 52786 [preauth]
```

Comment: `libssh2` may not be able to chat with the OpenSSH server due to not supporting compatible Key Exchange Methods (KEX) or MACs, especially if https://www.libssh2.org/ is out of date. Maybe the OpenSSH server could set compatible methods, or something else could be used on the client side?

Comment: I tried modifying the server HostkeyAlgorithms, but no luck. The client is sadly only accessible via web interface, which is quite limited - only public key export.